# How to partition by a transformed column in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to make use of year-month as partition in my table, but there is no such column in the table.

Is it possible to be partitioned by the custom field? For example I tried as below:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE table zhihu_answer partition (ym) 
SELECT 
answer_id,
answer_updated,
author_headline,
author_id,
author_name,
question_created,
question_id,
question_title,
question_type,
voteup_count,
date_format(insert_time,'yyyyMM') as ym
FROM zhihu_answer;
```

But it failed with:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ValidationFailureSemanticException table is not partitioned but partition spec exists: {ym=null}
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `zhihu_answer`(
      `answer_id` string, 
      `answer_updated` string, 
      `author_headline` string, 
      `author_id` string, 
      `author_name` string, 
      `insert_time` string, 
      `question_created` string, 
      `question_id` string, 
      `question_title` string, 
      `question_type` string, 
      `voteup_count` int)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      'hdfs://device1:8020/user/hive/warehouse/zhihu.db/zhihu_answer'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      'transient_lastDdlTime'='1569629962')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your destination table has to be created as partitioned table first.
 add partitioned by clause to your create table statement for table zhihu_answer.

    partitioned by (ym string)

Comment: set below property also set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;